# Why my linux command 'perf list' don't support hardware events like 'branches'?

Tags: linux, perf

I'm studying [performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2018](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2018/796439e646c02f44348d50b1836ff7f9_MIT6_172F18hw2.pdf) and doing Checkoff Item 1.
Using ubuntu in free Azure for student, But it doesn't support hardware events like 'branches'.

```bash
$ uname -r
6.2.0-1018-azure

$ perf --version
perf version 6.2.16

$ lscpu
...
model :Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8171M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Hypervisor vendor : Microsoft
Virtualization type : full
...

$ perf list

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e or -M):

  alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
  bpf-output                                         [Software event]
  cgroup-switches                                    [Software event]
  context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
  cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
  cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
  dummy                                              [Software event]
  emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
  major-faults                                       [Software event]
  minor-faults                                       [Software event]
  page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
  task-clock                                         [Software event]
  duration_time                                      [Tool event]
  user_time                                          [Tool event]
  system_time                                        [Tool event]
  msr/pperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/smi/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
       [(see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)]
  mem:<addr>[/len][:access]                          [Hardware breakpoint]
  sdt_libc:cond_broadcast                            [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:cond_destroy                              [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:cond_init                                 [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:cond_signal                               [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:cond_wait                                 [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:lll_lock_wait                             [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:lll_lock_wait_private                     [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:longjmp                                   [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:longjmp_target                            [SDT event]
  sdt_libc:memory_arena_new                          [SDT event]
```

it seems like that it doesn't support hardware events like branch-misses,cache-misses.

maybe I should build VM in my own desktop,but i don't have enough disk space :(

Comment: Because you're running in a VM which doesn't pass through PMU support.

Comment: I study something about cloud computing.Thanks for your answering.❤

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, in order to run your assessment, you need a proper hardware. In particular, one that allows the features and events described in your paper.

Virtual hardware like the Azure VM your are using isolates the guest operating system (yours) and does not allow it to fully control the attached hardware.

In this case, PMU events are not exposed since they would allow the user of a VM to disrupt the host.

Also, keep in mind, that virtualization software employs a vast array of optimization and shortcuts in order to achieve par performances with real hardware, thus you could observe a different behavior with respect to a physical, dedicated hardware.

You should try a real PC, either by dual booting or using a live usb stick.

Comment: Some VMs *do* support virtualizing the PMU hardware, or at least it was being worked on for Linux KVM.  It might not be ready yet, I forget.  Also, performance differences inside a VM are mostly that the `cpuid` instruction is much slower (always a VM exit), and TLB misses cost more (because of nested page tables: guest physical addresses are host-virtual, so there's another level of page tables.  For pure computation that doesn't cause to many page walks, all (or most) events that perf counters can measure should be close to the same inside a VM or not.

Comment: I study something about cloud computing.Thanks for your answering.❤